# Закрытие вкладок tabPage в tabControl c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в `TabControl` закрывая последнюю вкладку, сделать активной предыдущую вкладку.
Пример: Допустим четыре вкладки - закрывая последнюю четвёртую вкладку, активной должна сталь третья вкладка, а у меня закрывая четвертую вкладку становится активной первая вкладка.

Answer (score 2):

Описанная Вами ситуация воспроизводится только в Windows Forms. В WPF при удалении в TabControl последней вкладки, по умолчанию предпоследняя становится текущей.

Чтобы добиться аналогичного поведения в Windows Forms следует после удаления (закрытия) сразу же назначить нужную вкладку в качестве текущей.
Например, так:

```
// Удаляем последнюю вкладку
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
// Делаем предпоследнюю вкладку текущей
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1;
```